# Unable to connect to the MySQL server, org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException, Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, netbeans

I get the following error in a pop up window when I try to `Register MySQL Server`

```
Unable to connect to the MySQL server: 

org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: org.netbeans.api.db.explorer.DatabaseException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure 

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.. 

The server may not be running or your MySQL connection properties may not be set correctly. Do you want to edit your MySQL connection properties?
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In my case the J Driver file was missing. So First download the driver from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/
then install it. After installation it will in placed in

```
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar
```

(FYI: Yours driver version might be different.)

Now you had to add that file in netbeans i.e. goto Services > Driver.
Right click MySQL (Connector/ J Driver) > Customize
Click Add.

Give path

```
/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java-8.0.18.jar
```

Click OK.

Now Again right click MySQL (Connector/ J Driver) > Connect Using ...
OR 
(for connection of specific Schema) 
Right click MySQL Server at localhost:3306 > connect
Then right click the specific Schema you want to connect with.
FYI: For yours ease rename the default lengthy name to just the database name instead.

Give User name (usually root) and password and the Database.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by clicking No, deleting the MySQL instance that had been created and starting again but this time using all the defaults.

And also, make sure that in the `Admin Properties` tab, the path to `mysql.exe` etc is correct

Answer (score 0):

for me works add the driver for MySQL in Netbeans IDE -
like Adeel Raza wrote

link to download: [Connertor/J driver](https://mariadb.com/downloads/connectors/connectors-data-access/java8-connector/)

[Driver in Netbeans Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HBCgZ.png)

and there you add link to driver - after that in same place you set the new connection to your database